# Aggreagating using mean by removing NAs in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` as follows:

```
   ID   ID2     Col1      Col2     Col3     Col4 
1:  1    34   423.76    234.22   234.11   123.87
2:  2    34   154.24        NA   221.23   786.43
3:  3    11   423.13    234.67   234.65   123.54
```

And am aggregating by `sum`s and `mean`s as follows:

```
aggregated <- dt[, list(mean(Col1), mean(Col2), 
                   sum(Col3), mean(Col4)), by="ID,ID2"]
```

How can I ignore the `NA` in `Col2` so that I do not have to remove the entire row from the table and still get `Col2` mean?

I have tried:

```
aggregated <- dt[, list(mean(Col1), mean(Col2), 
                   sum(Col3), mean(Col4)),by="ID,ID2", na.rm = TRUE]
```

Comment: Look at `?mean`, specifically the `na.rm` argument.

Comment: In the mean itself...thanks.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the `data.table` package but it looks as if the `na.rm = TRUE` is not within any of the `mean` calls and therefore wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @Chaconne The mean function doesn't come from the `data.table` package, it's the same method that's in the `base` package.

Comment: My point was that the `na.rm = TRUE` wasn't within the `mean` calls and unless `data.table` has a functionality which I don't know about wherein arguments like that get passed to all functions in the brackets, then the `na.rm = TRUE` wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

The more idiomatic way to do it would be:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=list(ID, ID2)]
```

`.SD` is a `data.table` that represents each `by` group within `dt`, so here we (l)apply `mean` to each column within each `by` group.  The `na.rm=TRUE` argument specified in `lapply` is forwarded to `mean` (see `?lapply`).  This produces:

```
   ID ID2   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
1:  1  34 423.76 234.22 234.11 123.87
2:  2  34 154.24    NaN 221.23 786.43
3:  3  11 423.13 234.67 234.65 123.54
```

Note how we now have a `NaN`, as `mean(NA, na.rm=T)` is `NaN` if the only value there is to take the mean of is `NA` (compare to `mean(NA)`).  This is the case with your data because each row happens to also be a group (i.e. no repeating values of `ID-ID2`), which means that for the second group for `Col2`, the only value to take the mean of is `NA`.

This is a little more meaningful (grouping only by `ID2` now):

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=ID2]

   ID2  ID   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
1:  34 1.5 289.00 234.22 227.67 455.15
2:  11 3.0 423.13 234.67 234.65 123.54
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to try:

```
aggregated <- dt[,list(mean(Col1, na.rm = TRUE), mean(Col2, na.rm = TRUE), sum(Col3, na.rm = TRUE), mean(Col4, na.rm = TRUE)),by="ID, ID2"]
```

Hope this helps.